# gulp prevent duplicated dependent task execution

Tags: javascript, gulp

looking for some help in refactoring my gulp config file.

I have the following two tasks that both depend on a 3rd task. 
I'm trying to get the 3rd task to only run once and save the results instead of having that task run twice.

```
gulp.task('lint', function(done) {


gulp.task('lib', function(done) {


they both depend on gulp.task('default_preferences', gulp.series('default_preferences-pre'))
```

previously default_preferences was being called for **lint** & **lib**

```
gulp.task('lint', gulp.series('default_preferences') function(done) {


gulp.task('lib', gulp.series('build_number', 'default_preferences') function(done) {
```

I have tried to create a new task calling 'default_preferences' and parallel on **lint** and 
**lib** but then the preferences aren't being found.

```
gulp.task('createDefault', gulp.series('default_preferences', gulp.parallel('lib', 'lint')), function () {})
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious, thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

Hello instead of using gulp task you could try approaching the problem this way:

```
function lint (done){}

function lib (done){}

exports.default= series(default_preferences-pre, parallel(lint,lib));

exports.lint= lint;
exports.lib= lib;
```

i hope it helps you